# to rise to the importance of the moment

Tags: meaning-in-context

Help me please about the exact meaning of the phrase in bold, please!

> Treasury Secretary, who met the king during his tour of the region in mid-November, described him to John as a broken man unlikely **to rise to the
>   importance of the moment**.

I should note the king was encounter a revolution, and the president was trying to persuade him to act firmly.

Thanks endlessly.

Answer (score 1):

It's a variation of this sense of "rise" from [Lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/rise)

> 3.1 (rise to) Find the strength or ability to respond adequately to (a challenging situation)
>   *‘many participants in the race had never sailed before, but they rose to the challenge’*

So it means that the king was unlikely to be able to find the strength to respond to the revolution.